# pop-ups in ubuntu from 304.misrepush.com

Tags: ubuntu

How I can get rid of pop-ups from 304.misrepush.com? I use elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (64-bit) built on ubuntu 14.04 and the pop-ups "pop" on the top right of the screen independent of the browser I use, just pinned on the top right of the screen.
[image]

Comment: Note, that Freya is not supported anymore and that support for underlying Ubuntu 14.04 ends in about 2 weeks. Make sure to upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: When searching the internet, misrepush seems to be malware or virus you should remove. https://www.virusresearch.org/remove-misrepush-com-redirects/. Looks similar to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087450/how-to-remove-naganoadigei-com-popup-virus

Answer (score 0):

Misrepush is a malware that is usually installed with free software downloaded from unreliable sources. Preferred as much as possible the official repository of your distribution.
If you have properly partitioned your disk, you can reinstall the system without having to back up your files (root reinstall only) Otherwise, reinstalling your system completely seems to be the most secure solution.